# Preserve \n on jinja

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2

I have Flask-App and I have html page and i'm using jinja with it.
I have a table, and this is a specific column in the table:
                                {{ item["full_msg"] }}

item["full msg"] should be:

```
The
A
Team
```

(It contains "\n" after The, A, Team)

But it presents as:

```
The A Team
```

I've tried adding |safe - not working.

Tried adding multi line class like:

```
<td><div class="multiline">{{ item["full_msg"] }}</div></td>
```

Not working.

Looked at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control
But didn't find solution to my problem.

Also tried:

```
                                <td><div class="multiline">{% autoescape false %}{{ item["full_msg"] }}{% endautoescape %}</div></td>
```

But no good.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: try to give </br> statement

Comment: Not working. The output is The </br>A </br>Team. It's not actually creating new line

Answer (score 0):

Give Line breaks because html use line breaks instead \n

```
The </br>A </br>Team
```

Comment: Not working. The output is The </br>A </br>Team. It's not actually creating new line

Comment: need to pipe the result through safe in order for the <br> tags to take effect.   e.g. `{{ item.fullmessage | replace("\n", "<br>" | safe ) }}`